# Shall i convert dialog box to tab in web application

Tags: web-app

In [mywebsql](http://demo.mywebsql.net/), it is the web based front end for mysql database. Currently many database operations are done by dialogs  (alter table, alter index like that) but i think it can be better if i convert dialogs to tab. Is it good for user experience. Currently the focus is only on web, not cares about mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reference UI/UX/HI guidelines on **modality**, like this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Modal.html

I know you said mobile isn't relevant to your problem, but I think the general guidelines still apply, namely:

> In general, consider creating a modal context only when:
>
> - It’s critical to get the user’s attention
> - A self-contained task must be completed—or explicitly abandoned—to avoid leaving the user’s data in an ambiguous state

So do the operations currently handled by dialogs leave the database in an ambiguous state if they are not explicitly executed/committed or canceled/rolled back? If so, I would leave them in dialogs. Otherwise, I would try to avoid modality as much as possible so users can accomplish what they want to do in multiple ways and in the way (and sequence of steps) that makes the most sense to them.

As a side note, in general your app has a very impressive interface!